# @SpringBootTest and @Transactional causes test to freeze

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, spring-boot-test

When combining `@SpringBootTest` and `@Transactional` my test freezes and never recovers.

I've built a demonstration of the problem [here](https://github.com/coreyferguson/springboottest-transactional).

[`getAgain`](https://github.com/coreyferguson/springboottest-transactional/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/UserControllerTest.java#L51)  fails because of a unique constraint violation caused by the [`@Before`](https://github.com/coreyferguson/springboottest-transactional/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/UserControllerTest.java#L37). To solve this, I would normally include an [`@Transactional` above the class](https://github.com/coreyferguson/springboottest-transactional/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/UserControllerTest.java#L22) to automatically roll back my changes after each test. However, this causes the test to freeze and never recovers.

Any idea why these two annotations don't play well together?

Comment: Because you are getting a deadlock. You are starting the full application (yes that is what `@SpringBootTest` does) then you insert data (but the transaction is still open). Then you call a controller, which tries to open a transaction as well (remember that I told that you start the full application) but due to the other transaction not having ended it cannot read from the table. A deadlock.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can solve this?  I want to test my application end-to-end using an embedded database for a given set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make use of `@SqlGroup` to initialize your database instead of `ResourceDatabasePopulator`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "/testbed.sql"),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "/clear.sql") })
public class UserControllerTest {
```

I've made changes to your sample project and it works fine.
You can see them here: [springboottest-transactional](https://github.com/IlyaZinkovich/springboottest-transactional)